# Trying to hide logo on scroll and on windows size

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to coding and are trying to get a function for my nav to hide the logo and become fixed at top, but can not make this code to work.

```
function rekotex() {

  //Do something under 767 px.
  if (window.matchMedia) { 
    if(window.matchMedia("all and (max-width: 767px)").matches) {

        // Hide logo.
        jQuery("#logo-in-menu").hide();
    }

 } else { // Over 768px.

    // See if page is scrolled, if so hide Logo.
    var height = jQuery(window).scrollTop();

    if(height <= 1){
        jQuery("#logo-in-menu").show();
        jQuery(".header").css({"height":230});
    }

    else if(height > 1) {
        jQuery("#logo-in-menu").hide();
        jQuery(".header").css({"height":130});
    }

}

var doit;
    window.onresize = function(){
        clearTimeout(doit);
        doit = setTimeout(rekotex, 100);
    };
}
```

Comment: Can you create a DEMO?

Comment: Guruprasad Rao, I am new to Stack Overflow, do it suffice if I remove the Maintenance screen on the site for some minutes? So you can se it live?

Comment: Yea, Lets see what you got..

Comment: Thanks, tried jsfiddle but this is faster :) The site is http://rekotex.se/

Comment: The `js` is minified right? Can you just publish the non-minified version of `js`? and also let know which file the code is present?

Comment: You meen the menu-scroll.js ? How is it minified? The complete code inside it is what I have posted above. Anything else I can help I will, I need your help :)

Comment: The above code is in `menu-scroll.js`?

Comment: Yes thats correct :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check if the user is scrolling the page you should use $(window).scroll(function (event), I THINK that what you want is this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    if(window.matchMedia("all and (max-width: 767px)").matches) {
        //Do something under 767 px.
        // Hide logo.
        jQuery("#logo-in-menu").hide();
    } else {// Over 768px.
    function rekotex() {
    // See if page is scrolled, if so hide Logo.
    var height = jQuery(window).scrollTop();

    if(height <= 1){
        jQuery("#logo-in-menu").show();
        jQuery(".header").css({"height":230});
    }

    else if(height > 1) {
        jQuery("#logo-in-menu").hide();
        jQuery(".header").css({"height":130});
    }

}


var doit;
    $(window).scroll(function (event) {
        clearTimeout(doit);
        doit = setTimeout(rekotex, 100);
    });
}
});
```

When the page loads, checks if the width is under 768 and if so, hides the logo, otherwise declares the function and hides the logo if the user scrolls

Also this is just a hunch, but is the setTimeout meant to be a fadeout animation? If so, you should write the time in the .hide().

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is using jQuery:

```
       $(document).on( 'scroll', function(){
            $('#image').hide()
       });
```

Comment: Thanks ThomH, I did that at first but that did not work as I need it to allways hide under 767px width. And to re-check the width if the page change size.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with this code.

```
#CSS
  #logo-in-menu { // Göm i mobil
    display: none !important;
  }

  .header {
    height: 75px !important;
  }

#JS
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
    var height = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
    if(height <= 1){
       jQuery("#logo-in-menu").show();
       jQuery(".header").css({"height":180});
    }
    else if(height > 1) {
        jQuery("#logo-in-menu").hide();
        jQuery(".header").css({"height":75});
    }
});
```